# Error in<>: Object of type 'closure' is not subsettable still do not know how to fix it

Tags: r

I get a error message on my code and can not figure it out .
I google some questions but still confuse about the solution.
I will be very appreciate if you can check my code and help me to solve this issue.
Thanks a lot.
My code is:

```
rm(list = ls())
    library(XLConnect)
    setwd('C:/Users/YL1/Desktop/Air Qulaity/Power Plant/
          NOx_SO2_Emission') # replace it with your own directory
    file <- 'C:/Users/YL1/Desktop/Air Qulaity/
        Power Plant/NOx_SO2_Emission/
        Total Emission_2003-2015.xlsx'
    wb <- loadWorkbook(file)
    dt <- lapply(2003:2015, function(x) readWorksheet(wb, sheet = as.character(x)))
    dt <- do.call(rbind, dt)
    colnames(dt) <- c('State', 'Facility.Name', 'Facility.ID.ORISPL', 'Year', 
                      'SO2.tons', 'NOx.tons')

    dt.select.fun <- function(station) {
      dt.select <- dt[dt$Facility.Name == station, ]
      dt.select <- dt.select[order(-dt.select$Year), ]
      write.csv(dt.select, paste0(station, '.csv'))
      return(dt.select)
    }

    # change station to other values to extract the emission in other stations
    dt.select.fun(station = 'Coffeen')


> Error in dt$Facility.Name : object of type 'closure' is not
> subsettable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably because your  `dt <- do.call(rbind, dt)` results in a matrix. Moreover, you are indexing in a function. Replace that with

```
dt <- do.call(rbind, dt) %>% as.data.table # to make a datatable
```

When you are calling your function , where are you passing data table ?

*update*:

```
dt.select.fun <- function(data,y) {
      dt.select <- data[data$Facility.Name == y, ]
      dt.select <- dt.select[order(-dt.select$Year), ]
      write.csv(dt.select, paste0(station, '.csv'))
      return(dt.select)
    }
# call the function on your data table
 dt.select.fun(dt,"Coffeen")
```

Comment: Thanks. but the problem is still there.

Comment: Thanks for update ! It seems work but I get new error:Error in dt.select.fun(dt, station = "898") : unused argument (dt). If you like to get more details I can send my code and data for your review. Please leave an email. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you  need to pass the argument to your function `dt.select.fun <- function(dt,station) {...your code...  return(dt.select)    }`

Comment: Hi I change the code as below but still get the error message:`Error in dt$Facility.Name : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. But the problem is still there. Please check the code I posted below.

Comment: Check the updated version. The error is because you are passing `df`as parameter in function and using `dt` in the function code. dt is a null hence, it is not subsettable . The update should work

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for your help. It totally works ! I appreciate your help very much !~

Comment: I have rate your answer but it not show up. But the your update made my day ! Best Regards

Comment: Hi, I just accept your answer. But I can not up-vote it due to my reputation. Thanks for your help !

Comment: No problem. Thank you. Appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help !

Comment: Hi @user5249203, Thank you very much for your help. I have another R question and would you help me to check it ? Thanks !http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635894/how-to-calculate-the-annual-average-from-time-series-data